# sql sum all values in col x for values smaller than value of x in this row

Tags: sql

How can I sum all values of c2 where the value in c1 is smaller or equal to the value of c1. I am confused as how to address the value of this row as the statement

```
sum(case c1 <= c1 then c2 else 0 end)
```

does not make much sense. how can I make it something like

```
sum(case c1 <= c1_value_of_this_row then c2 else 0 end)

c1    c2
 1    10
 2     5
 1     3
 3     8
```

to

```
c1    c2
 1    13
 2    18
 3    26
```

Comment: What is meant by c1 as the  value of this row and what is the difference compared to ordinary c1? The result seems like a simple group by clause with  sum()

Comment: it s not a sum. it s a sum of all values in c2 over all rows where c1 is smaller or equal to the value of c1 in the output table.
so, in the output table the row with c1 shows them sum of all rows where the value in c1 <=1; the second row shows the sum of all the values of rows where c1 <=2, .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a running total.

```
select C1,
       max(C2) as C2
from (
     select C1,
            sum(C2) over(order by C1 rows unbounded preceding) as C2
     from YourTable
     ) T
group by C1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63eedc/6)